# Tracking Facebook post likes per admin

Tags: facebook, statistics

Is there any way to track the amount of likes per poster gets? [The term "likes" refers also to the new "reactions" on Facebook.]

For a little bit of background, if you're not familiar with how Facebook pages work when they have multiple admins or editors, [this picture shows if you have multiple people who manage the page, Facebook tracks the person who published the post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhKXR.png) Now with this in mind, is there any way through the Facebook API or other to track the amount of likes a post gets and associate them with the publisher?

For example, Admin 1 posts 2 posts, one with 2 likes and another with 7 likes. Admin 2 then posts 3 posts, one with 6, one with 1, and one with 4. I would like for it to track that Admin 1 has gotten 9 likes and Admin 2 has gotten 11 likes. Having it keep track of the amount of posts per admin would also be great. This would make for a great system to reward admins who post more enjoyable or well-received content. Having it track other stats such as post reach, comments, etc. would also be great.

Now before any of you say that I could do this manually, I'd like a real-time count. Doing it manually is definitely possible but a real-time count (or a refresh at a certain interval) would definitely be better, easier, more accurate (especially with bigger pages who constantly get new likes on old posts).

If this is possible, it would be amazing!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You’ll need to read the likes/reactions for the posts as you would normally do; and then also request the field `admin_creator`, which will hold the user that created the post. (You need to use a page access token for this request, only then this field is available.)

Comment: @CBroe I've been able to get the fields using this: PAGE_ID/feed?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),admin_creator however I would like to see if there's a way to automatically sort by admin and like the post likes together for a certain period of time